# Check boxes for Unicorn Sync on Helix Projects not shown

Tags: helix, habitat, unicorn

On my machine, I am able to sync all content across all Helix projects

On my colleagues machine, she doesn't see any check boxes or projects at all with no error displayed.

According to Kamsar, https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/issues/108, this may be due to any of these conditions not being met:

```
MultipleConfigurationsExist && 
 configurationHasAnySerializedItems && 
 configurationHasValidRootPaths
```

But they should all be met in this case. Any suggestions? Is there a Unicorn log I can check?

Steve

Comment: If you can demonstrate that each of the conditions are met then you will likely find the issue. I most often see this occur when one of the root items is not yet synced.

Comment: If you see no checkboxes I agree with Michael. 99% of the time, it comes down to missing root items.  If you don't see any projects at all, I suspect you're not patching in the configs correctly. Try a showconfig.aspx to validate

Comment: also remember that you can go to `http://mysite/unicorn.aspx?verb=sync` and that will do the same as Sync All The Things, of course, there may be errors in the sync, but its sometimes a quick way of finding them :)

Comment: I agree with Richard, I wouldn't worry about trying to use the UI if all you want to do is Sync changes, just hit the url he provided and you are all set to go.